# How to make a IP grabber?

Tags: ip-address, ip-geolocation

Just like where the ip of the victim is logged once he clicks the generated link sent to him.

How can I make an ***IP grabber*** from scratch? It can be a script, program or website.

I want to know the languages, tools and approach that are used to grab IP of someone far away.

Comment: There are different web sites you can use. e,g, https://ipv4.wtfismyip.com/text  But if you want to make a site like that yourself you need to find a web hoster that allows you to run code on the server.

Comment: thanks i found a code snippet to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atlast ,I found something in PHP to get the work done

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
file_put_contents('logs.txt', $ip, FILE_APPEND);
```

This ip can be used to trace the location and fetch other details  using **http://ipinfo.io** APIs or **https://wtfismyip.com/**  APIs There are many other APIs though but available the above don't need registeration.

```
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json"));
```

Hope this helps you as well.